# Openapi swagger start lead to nestjs could not find Connection element

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, typeorm, openapi

I need some help, if anyone has already faced this, i can't handle why is it happening !
If i do any kind of start (dev or prod) it work properly, but when i need to update openapi.yaml by doing `node dist/openapi.js` it don't work.

It throw a node nestjs error :

```
2023-06-26T09:45:01+02:00 - OmsModule dependencies initialized
(node:10136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Nest could not find Connection element (this provider does not exist in the current context)
    at ContainerScanner.getWrapperCollectionPairByHost (C:\Users\ostorero-gu\Documents\projects\oms-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\container-sca
nner.js:34:19)
    at ContainerScanner.findInstanceByToken (C:\Users\ostorero-gu\Documents\projects\oms-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\container-scanner.js:20:
40)
    at Object.findInstanceByToken (C:\Users\ostorero-gu\Documents\projects\oms-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\module-ref.js:40:38)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\ostorero-gu\Documents\projects\oms-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\module.js:341:29)
    at TypeOrmCoreModule.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ostorero-gu\Documents\projects\oms-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:94:47)   
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\ostorero-gu\Documents\projects\oms-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:20:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\ostorero-gu\Documents\projects\oms-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:16:12)
    at TypeOrmCoreModule.onApplicationShutdown (C:\Users\ostorero-gu\Documents\projects\oms-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js
:90:16)
(node:10136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without
 a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:10136) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will term
inate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

So i got two connection with my db declared in my app.module.ts :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerModule,
    ConfigurationModule,
    HealthcheckModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigurationModule],
      inject: [ConfigurationService],
      useFactory: async (configurationService: ConfigurationService) => {
        return ({
          type: 'oracle',
          extra: {
            connectString: configurationService.get(ConfigurationKeys.GOLDCONNECTSTRING),
          },
          username: configurationService.get(ConfigurationKeys.GOLDUSERNAME),
          password: configurationService.get(ConfigurationKeys.GOLDPASSWORD),
          database: '',
          entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
          synchronize: false,
          logging: false,
        }) as TypeOrmModuleOptions;
      },
    }),
    HealthcheckTypeormModule.register({
      name: 'GOLD',
      type: 'oracle',
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigurationModule],
      name: 'reflex',
      inject: [ConfigurationService],
      useFactory: async (configurationService: ConfigurationService) => {
        return ({
          type: 'postgres',
          host: configurationService.get(ConfigurationKeys.REFLEXHOST),
          database: configurationService.get(ConfigurationKeys.REFLEXDB),
          username: configurationService.get(ConfigurationKeys.REFLEXUSERNAME),
          password: configurationService.get(ConfigurationKeys.REFLEXPASSWORD),
          synchronize: false,
          logging: false,
        }) as TypeOrmModuleOptions;
      },
    }),
    OmsModule,
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(HelmetMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

"Reflex" connection is used in two repository :

```
@Injectable()
export class ReflexRepository {

  private static readonly TAG = 'ReflexRepository';

  constructor(
    @InjectConnection('reflex') private readonly connection: Connection,
    private readonly logger: LoggerService,
  ) {
  }

  public async getOrderPreparation(orderPreparationNumber: string): Promise<Array<ReflexModelOrderPreparation>> {

    let queryResult;
    const query = ReflexRepository.getOrderPreparationSql(orderPreparationNumber);

    try {
      queryResult = await this.connection.query(query);
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.error(ReflexRepository.TAG, e.message);
      throw e;
    }

    return queryResult;
  }

  private static getOrderPreparationSql(orderPreparationNumber: string): string {
    return `private query`;
  }

  async getTrackingByOrderNumber(orderNumber: string): Promise<TrackingCommandeEntity[]> {
    const result = this.connection.getRepository(TrackingCommandeEntity).find({ NUM_CDE_CLT: orderNumber });
    if ((await result).length <= 0) { throw new NotFoundError('Tracking pour la commande introuvable'); }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Here is my OmsModule :

```
@Module({
  imports: [ProduitsModule],
  controllers: [OmsController],
  providers: [OmsService, GoldRepository, OmsMapper, ReflexRepository],
})

export class OmsModule {
}
```

At the end maybe it will be useful, here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "oms-api",
  "version": "5.6.1",
  "description": "blablalbla",
  "author": "test",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "prestart:prod": "rimraf dist && tsc --p tsconfig.prod.json",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
    "prestart:openapi": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "start:openapi": "node dist/openapi.js",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "sonar-scanner": "sonar-scanner"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "xxxxPrivateURLxxxxxx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nest-middlewares/helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.11.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.11.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.10.14",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^3.1.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.2.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.11.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "oracledb": "^4.2.0",
    "pg": "^8.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "4.17.21",
    "@types/babel__traverse": "7.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^6.11.11",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.0",
    "@types/js-yaml": "^3.12.2",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/node": "14.18.51",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "js-yaml": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "tslint-sonarts": "^1.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../test/coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance, any help appreciated !

I tried many weird things because i don't understand where the problem come from, why openapi is'nt working..

Here is my openapi.builder.ts :

```
export function createDocument(app: INestApplication, versionPrefix = false, enableBearerAuth = false): SwaggerDocument {
  const title = process.env.npm_package_name;
  const version = process.env.npm_package_version;
  const description = process.env.npm_package_description;

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle(title)
    .setDescription(description)
    .setVersion(version);

  if (enableBearerAuth) {
    options.addBearerAuth();
  }

  const configuration = options.build();
  return SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, configuration);
}
```

and openapi.ts :

```
async function run() {
  const logger = new LoggerService();
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { logger });
  const outputPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'openapi.yaml');

  const document = createDocument(app, true);

  if (!document.definitions) document.definitions = {};

  try {
    writeFileSync(outputPath, toYaml(document, { schema: JSON_SCHEMA }), { encoding: 'utf8' });
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(`Error while creation yaml openapi : ${e.message}`);
  }

  await app.close();
}

run();
```

used in main.ts here :

```
async function run() {
  const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
  const apiDocsPath = '/api-docs';

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { logger: new LoggerService() });

  //Uncomment if needed
  //app.enableShutdownHooks();

  app.enableCors();

  const document = createDocument(app);

  if (environment !== 'prod' && environment !== 'preprod') {
    SwaggerModule.setup('swagger', app, document);
  }

  app.use(apiDocsPath, (req, res) => res.send(document));
  await app.listen(3000);
}

run();
```

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER :
I found this post: [Nest could not find Sequelize element when calling `app.close()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754461/nest-could-not-find-sequelize-element-when-calling-app-close)

The answer was explaining that we must double name the second db connection in order  getConnectionToken can get the name from the options of the connection.
The first connection has default name, you don't need to name it expressively.

Example :

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigurationModule],
  inject: [ConfigurationService],
  useFactory: async (configurationService: ConfigurationService) => {
    return ({
      type: 'oracle',
      blabla: 'blabla'
    }) as TypeOrmModuleOptions;
  },
}),
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigurationModule],
  // REQUIRED NAME
  name: 'reflex',
  inject: [ConfigurationService],
  useFactory: async (configurationService: ConfigurationService) => {
    return ({
      // HERE NAME REQUIRED ALSO
      name: 'reflex',
      type: 'postgres',
      blabla: 'blabla'
    }) as TypeOrmModuleOptions;
  },
}),
```